# API URL to post json formatted data

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, url

How would I transfer code from textfields into json formatted data.

Below is the current code i have, but it doesn't seem to transfer the data within the textfields to json when the button is clicked. Is their any errors within this code?

```
@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // parse in paramaters
    let parameters = ["Name": nameTextField, "Email": emailTextField, "DOB": dateTextField] as [String : Any]

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://prod-69.westeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/d2ec580e6805459893e498d43f292462/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zn8yq-Xe3cOCDoRWTiLwDsUDXAwdGSNzxKL5OUHJPxo") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    // let url session know that this is a post request
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // convert paramaters to JSON
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `nameTextField.text!` etc. ?

Comment: I'd suggest also using `?? ""` afterward to avoid an exception for any reason.

Comment: Don't ignore errors. Replace `try?` with `try` in a `do/catch` so you know what the problem is.

Comment: @KSigWyatt The `text` property of `UITextField` is indeed optional but is never `nil` in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Are `nameTextField`, `emailTextField` and `dateTextField` of type `String` or `UITextField`. Make sure you are passing the `UITextField.text` property and not the `UITextField` itself.

See below:

```
guard let name = nameTextField.text,
    let email = emailTextField.text,
    let dob = dateTextField.text else {
        return
}

let parameters: [String: String] = ["name": name, "email": email, "dob": dob]
```